# Second network interface not showing up in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a machine that has a network adapter on the motherboard as well as a PCI dual-port network card. It seems the PCI card is not being recognized by Ubuntu at all. How do I fix this?

When I run `/sbin/ip -4 -o a | cut -d ' ' -f 2,7 | cut -d '/' -f 1` it returns:

```
lo 127.0.0.1 
enp0s31f6 130.207.140.169
```

This means Ubuntu only sees one network interface, right?

when I run `lspci` the only thing obviously network related in the list is:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
```

This means Ubuntu doesn't even see the other network card, right?

How do I get Ubuntu to recognize my second network card and have it show up in the list of network interfaces?

Comment: Switching the PCI slot it was plugged into did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched which PCI slot the card was plugged into and upon reboot, it is now showing up both in `lspci` and `ifconfig`.